# sine-tone generation with sin(double) fills out blocks of memory unexpectedly

Tags: c, audio-recording, waveform

I’m writing a code in c that outputs data in a file. The code generation (amplitude) function isn’t yet well defined. At compile it runs ok but the output isn’t what I expected. Even with `dwVal=0` the output is the same : a string of ascending values and not a sine.

```
long dwData=200;
HGLOBAL hData=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwLength);
int wData=(int)GlobalLock(hData);//no cast to (int)

    for(int i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        DWORD dwVal=16384*sin((double)i/20*pi);
        memset(&wData+i, dwVal, 2);
    };

//save data
    if (!PathFileExists(szName1))
        strcpy(szName1, "output.pcm");

FILE* file=fopen(szName1, "wb");
    for(i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        DWORD j=fputc((int)&wData+i, file);
        if (j==EOF){
            cvar.mbsz("error writing", "titlu", j);
            return;
        };
    };
    fclose(file);
```

Please help me clarify what’s wrong in the first part (the sine generation) and how it should look like. Many thanks for your time.

*EDIT*

```
int *wData=(int*)GlobalLock(hData);//no cast to (int)

DWORD dwVal;
    for(int i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        dwVal=16384*sin(pi/20*(long)i);
        wData[i]=dwVal;
    };

FILE* file=fopen(szName1, "wb");
DWORD j;
    for(i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        j=fwrite(&wData[i], 1, 1, file);
        if (j==EOF){
            return;
        };
    };
    fclose(file);
```

Thank you MSalters. I tried to do some replacement here and there but can’t say it compiles. I’m a newby in C++, and I need it in C++… can you write down for me the `for` loop. If you agree with me, the dwVal variable isn’t necessary to be an array. dwLength is a finite length (200).

Thank you Michael Waltz for your observations!

```
double pi=3.1415926535;
long dwData=200;
HGLOBAL hData=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwLength);
long *wData=(long*)GlobalLock(hData);

long dwVal;
    for(int i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        dwVal=16384*sin(i/20*pi);
        wData[i]=dwVal;
    };

//save data
    if (!PathFileExists(szName1))
        strcpy(szName1, "output.pcm");

FILE* file=fopen(szName1, "wb");
    for(i=0;i<dwLength;i++){
        DWORD j=fwrite(&wData[i], 2, 1, file);
        if (j==EOF){
            cvar.mbsz("error writing", "titlu", 0);
            return;
        };
    };
    fclose(file);
```

The way I close &Release objects and file is ok?

Comment: What's the content of `dwLength` ?

Comment: Worse part is that I replied a topic just as my own and gave a reply in C that now doubt it will work. When I'll be back I will search for it and re do the verifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
    DWORD dwLength = 200 ;
    HGLOBAL hData=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwLength);

    int *wData=(int*)GlobalLock(hData);

    for(int i = 0;i < dwLength; i++){
        wData[i] = 16384 * sin( (double)i / 20 * PI );
    }
```

You should learn some C basics before going on.

Comment: Yes, it runs ok but the output pcm has expected contents. I'm sorry to be a newby and receiving minuses for my topics but I want this program to run smooth, perhaps I will make it run with your help. Also, pls excuse my english for not understanding MSalters in the first place. My app needs to write Unicode chr$ in a RIFF file along with this code of dwLength. This sine code will be stored in the file and the app will look up these codes and return one Unicode chr. Thank you M. Waltz

Answer (score 2):

`memset` is not the assignment operator. ALso, `GlobalLock` returns a pointer with good reason. Don't cast that to a non-pointer type. Since you are tyring to store `DWORD`, cast it to a `DWORD*`, select the array element with `[i]` and use the `=` assignment operator.